# Is it possible to restrict availability of an Android widget by manafacturer?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'd like to make a widget available for a specific manafacturer. Is it possible to prevent a widget from appearing in the widgets gallery for specific devices, given that anyone is able to install the application?